# i have this problem: Binding element 'userName' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript

I want tp create simple CRUD with TypeScript,

I have user.json with data. This file path is declared as a variable and I convert this using `JSON.parse()`.

I want want to use this in get data, however, I get

> Binding element 'userName' implicitly has an 'any' type

See the comment

```
const path = '../db/users.json';
import fs from 'fs'

interface users{
  id: number;
  userName: string;
};

const acc: users = JSON.parse(path)
// export type test = typeof user;
// let userAccont: typeof user;

const getAccounts = () => {
  const jsonData = fs.readFileSync(path)
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonData))    
}

const getOneAcount = ({
  id,
  userName // Binding element 'userName' implicitly has an 'any' type
}){
  const existAccounts = getAccounts();
  let foundedAcount = null;
  if (userName) {
    const foundedByUserName = existAccounts.find((ac) => ac.userName === userName);
    if (foundedByUserName) foundedAcount = foundedByUserName
    console.log({foundedByUserName})
  }
  return foundedAcount
}
```

Comment: Is `getOneAcount` meant to be an arrow function? It looks like you might be missing the arrow.

Comment: @DBS yes...even TS complains about that exact thing: https://tsplay.dev/WozQjm